# Get private IP of VM in Azure Dev Test Lab using Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-devtest-labs

Just now I started with Azure DevTest Lab. I created a VM in lab using a json template. I want to use the public IP of the VM using powershell or may be I would like to return the same using template, if I can.

The challenge here is as per DTL concept the VM is created in a new resource group other than the one where your lab exists. I can definitely see the name of resource group of lab VM on portal but I am not able to figure out how this can be done using powershell. I am working on an automation so I need to do it by powershell.

Refer to the picture. The lab seems to be in a resource group in the same where the lab exist shown in green box. But, technically the lab VM resides in dynamically created resource gruop (RG name pattern = labname + VM name + Some Random digits) shown in light yellow in screenshot.

[image]

Comment: so whats the problem?

Comment: Problem is how to get the VM IP without knowing the name of the resource group using powershell

Comment: well, you know devtestlabs name

Comment: Yes I know the devtestlab name. RG name pattern = labname + VM name + Some Random digits.
I have no clue on the last part "some random number"

Comment: do you know vmname? or do you need to determine it dynamically?

Comment: I know the VM Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other solutions are helpful but not complete. I am doing in this way - I am returning the default output of template that is vmId. Refer from template  [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devtestlab/blob/master/ARMTemplates/101-dtl-create-vm-username-pwd-customimage-with-expiration/azuredeploy.json/)

Now we need to manipulate this vmId to get the name of resource group where the lab VM has been created.

```
$result = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "aatifdtlrg207912" -TemplateFile "D:\AzureDeploy.json" -TemplateParameterObject $paramValues
$VMId = $result.outputs.Values.value
$VMComputeId = (Get-AzureRmResource -Id $VMId).Properties.ComputeId
$RGNameofVM = $VMComputeId.split("/")
$RGNameofVM = $RGNameofVM[4] 
$IP = (Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $VMName -ResourceGroupName $RGNameofVM ).IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, generally a more elegant solution, oposed to bruteforce would be to use `Get-AzureRmResource`

```
$Resource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId "/subscriptions/$sub_GUID/resourcegroups/$RG_devlab_Name/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/labs/$LabName/virtualmachines/$VMName"
$Resource.Properties.computeId -match 'resourceGroups/(.+)/providers'
$RGName = $Matches[1]
$IP = (Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $VMName-ResourceGroupName $RGName).IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as we know for DevTest Labs there is no direct way for powershell. You can use the below powershell script to get the Private IP Address of the VM by just passing the Virtual machine name. We can use `Find-AzureRmResource` and `Get-AzureRmResource` by passing the ResourceId:

```
$vmNicdetails = Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceNameContains mytestVM | Where {$_.ResourceType -eq 'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces'}
$nicdetails = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $vmNicdetails.ResourceId
$ipconfig = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId
$nicdetails.Properties.ipConfigurations.id -ApiVersion '2017-03-01'
$ipconfig.Properties.privateIPAddress
```